# Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I'm trying to retrieve all records within the 'request_item' model that belongs to 'profile' model and the 'profile' model has blob column.

```
$items = request_item::orderBy('created_at','asc')->orderBy('updated_at','asc')->take(200)->get();
foreach($items as $i):
   $i->name = $i->profile->fullname;
   $i->item_name = $i->inventory->item_name;
endforeach;

return response()->json([ 'success' => true, 'items' => $items ]);
```

As you can see from the above codes, i take 200 records, order by 'created_at' and 'updated_at' on a ascending order and then I loop through the objects and create a attribute named 'name' that contains the object 'fullname' from the parent model 'profile' and return it as a json response (Ajax request from the front end). Here's the 'request_item' model and 'profile_model'

'profile' model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class profile extends Model
{
    protected $table = "profiles";
    protected $primaryKey = "username";
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function request_item(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\request_item','username');
    }

}
```

and the 'request_item' model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class request_item extends Model
{
    protected $table = "request_items";

    public function profile(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\profile','username');
    }
}
```

but it gives me this error from the response

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Base in this error, I'm sure it refers to the blob image the goes along with the retrieved objects from the 'profile' model, even though I specify to get only the 'fullname' (I have no idea, why the 'blob' column is pulled along with the 'fullname')

```
$i->profile->fullname;
```

So, is there a way I could transform the blob to base64 so that it can be a valid json response? I know I could do it like

```
 base64_encode($data);
```

but I just don't know where to insert it, which part, which line? or is there a way I could done it through the model? like it will be automatically converted to base64 when I pull it?

PS: I'm running on Laravel 5.2